# struts2 and freemarker template

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

i use struts2 on my web app, in one jsp file i display 3 arraylist in a form using "iterator".

when i launch my app with tomcat everything works fine. but i would like to make it works with websphere6.1, but when i launch it now the page take 20-30 second to appears, with tomcat it was lass than 1 second.

here is the logs i have on my websphere console :

> (freemarker.cache                    81  ) Could not find template in cache, creating new one; id=[template/simple/form.ftl[fr_FR,UTF-8,parsed] ]

i have almost 9000 lines of this kind before page appears.

i tried to create a file "freemarker.properties" with prop :

```
template_update_delay=60000
```

also tried to extract the "template/simple" in my source root, on WEB-INF... nothing !

do you have any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find template in cache

The template folder should copy to `WEB_APP root` instead of `WEB-INF`.
My suggestion : Rename the template folder to `templates` for distinguished from default.

```
<constant name="struts.ui.templateDir" value="templates" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

---

Refer to [Performance tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/performance-tuning.html) of Struts2 :

1. **Turn off logging and devMode**
   Make sure to turn off [**Freemarker Logging**](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html) (esp. Freemarker generates a LOT of logging).
2. **Try to use the Freemarker equivalent rather than using the JSP tags**
   `<s:property value="foo"/>` should be replaced by `${foo}` (except for type conversion), great performancing enhancing for **iterator**.